# What are the days when fast is haram or makruh?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, shiism, sawm

Can people clear me what are the days when fast is haram or makruh for men and women?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here I mentioned Haram&Makruh Day's Based On Ayatollah Sistani oponion{1}:

**Makruh:**

1. When you are not sure the day is Arafe (عرفه) or it is Qurban (قربان)

**Haraam**

1. Day Of Fetr (عید فطر)
2. Day Of Qurban (عید قربان)
3. When you are not sure the day is 1'st of Ramazan or 30's of Shaban, and you fast with intent of 1'st ramazan (This is Haram)
4. In Mustahab Fast, if your parents deny you. or if they dont deny but you know your fast is hard to them and put them in pain.

5.when you give a high probability that fasting have a serious bad infect on your body.

there are some other days which fasting in them is Haram. but they are rare and I did not find and mentioned them here.

**Reference:**

1.https://www.sistani.org/persian/book/50/72/

Answer (score 0):

The fast is haram in eiddain(eid ul fitar& eid ul azha).The fast is also haram in case of manses for ladies.

Answer (score 0):

On which days is fasting forbidden or makrooh?
Fasting on Eid al-Adha and Eid al-Fitr, the days of Tashreeq, is haram for one who is in Mina, as well as the day when a person doubts that it is the end of Sha'ban or the beginning of Ramadan, which is haram if he fasts with the first intention of Ramadan.
Just fasting on Sunday or Ashura without Tasua, Nowruz, fasting a woman without her husband's permission are all makrooh. Fasting is makrooh these days.

Ref;https://www.aftabir.com/articles/view/religion/ahkam/c7_1527754733p1.php/%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2%D9%87-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%DA%86%D9%87-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA